# Plugins doesn't work after installation in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gvim, vim-plugins

I have followed the Installing plugins in the book Mastering Vim. But it doesn't work when I try it. What can I do?

Here is what I have done. I only show what I believe is important:

````
" See page 50 in the book Mastering Vim by Rusland Osipov 2018.
" This will load documentation for each plugin, as it doesn't do so
" automatically.
packloadall               " Load all plugins.
silent! helptags All      " Load help files for all plugins.
.vimrc (END)

$ gvim -V
.
.
.

sourcing "$HOME/.vimrc"
not found in 'packpath': "pack/*/start/*"
not found in 'packpath': "pack/*/start/*"
finished sourcing $HOME/.vimrc

.
.
.

chdir(/home/colmin)
fchdir() to previous dir
could not source "$HOME/.gvimrc"
chdir(/home/colmin/.vim)
fchdir() to previous dir
could not source "~/.vim/gvimrc"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Open.png"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Open.xpm"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Open.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Save.png"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Save.xpm"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Save.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/SaveAll.png"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/SaveAll.xpm"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/SaveAll.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Print.png"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Print.xpm"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Print.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Undo.png"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Undo.xpm"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Undo.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Redo.png"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Redo.xpm"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Redo.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Cut.png"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Cut.xpm"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Cut.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Copy.png"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Copy.xpm"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Copy.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Paste.png"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Paste.xpm"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Paste.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Replace.png"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Replace.xpm"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Replace.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/FindNext.png"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/FindNext.xpm"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/FindNext.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/FindPrev.png"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/FindPrev.xpm"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/FindPrev.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/LoadSesn.png"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/LoadSesn.xpm"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/LoadSesn.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/SaveSesn.png"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/SaveSesn.xpm"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/SaveSesn.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/RunScript.png"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/RunScript.xpm"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/RunScript.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Make.png"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Make.xpm"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Make.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/RunCtags.png"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/RunCtags.xpm"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/RunCtags.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/TagJump.png"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/TagJump.xpm"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/TagJump.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Help.png"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Help.xpm"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Help.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/FindHelp.png"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/FindHelp.xpm"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/FindHelp.bmp"
XSMP handling save-yourself requestcolmin@hp-sitting-room:~$ ```
````

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried what was written in the book, but that didn't work. When I put in Ruby plugins they worked. It's only the Ruby plugins that I need for now so the problems is solved for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have discovered that the plugins work even with Vim plugins. The problem was that I had written the commands in LibreOffice with .txt. I need to write it in the terminal and then copy it if I want to save it in LibreOffice. And then copy it from LibreOffice to the terminal.